# Rendering problems the following classes could not be found

Tags: android, intellij-idea, drawerlayout

Im working on an `Android` app in `Intellij Idea` following [this tutorial](http://codetheory.in/android-navigation-drawer/) for `Navigation Drawer` *(Using API 17)*

After creating the main layout, There's no actual error. But when I try to open the layout in design mode, I'm getting this error.

```
rendering problems
the following classes could not be found:
- android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
```

*activity_main.xml*

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!-- The main content view -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainContent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

...

</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Why this is happening. Does it has anything to do with the API I'm using?

Comment: Have you added the support design dependency in your build.gradle file?

Comment: @jaibatrik I have no idea what is that!

Comment: At the left pane where the project structure is shown, under "Gradle Scripts", you should see build.gradle file for your project. You should add `compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.0.1'` to the dependencies section in that file.

Comment: @jaibatrik But there is no `Gradle Scripts` in the left pane

Comment: Is there a link called "Project" in the left pane?

Comment: Like the bottom left here - https://gdgoakdale.github.io/firebase-android-codelab-gdg-oakdale/images/screenshot-20150415-project-import.png

Comment: @jaibatrik I solved it and posted the answer. Thank you for your concern

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I've found what I was missing. I needed to add `android.support.v4` to my project. and once I did that. The problem has been solved.

[This is the page](https://www.in-nomine.org/2012/02/26/adding-android-support-v4-to-your-android-application-in-intellij-idea/) which helped me to do that.

> You can enable support for certain forward version features via the
>   android.support namespace. In order to accomplish this you need to
>   start the Android SDK Manager and make sure that under the Extras
>   heading you select and install the Android Support package.
>
> Once done you go into the directory extras/android/support/v4 and copy
>   the android-support-v4.jar to your own project’s libs directory. Next
>   go within IntelliJ IDEA to File » Project Structure and under Project
>   Settings go to Modules, make sure your application is selected in the
>   middle pane, then on the right side select the Dependencies tab. In
>   the window below click the plus-icon and select Jars or directories.
>   From the resulting window browse to your libs directory and select the
>   android-support-v4.jar and press OK to close the window and add the
>   jar-file to the dependencies of the project. Since you are now using
>   certain constants from a newer version of Android the Module SDK needs
>   to be changed to Android 4.0.3 Platform as well. Press Apply and close
>   the Project Settings by pressing the OK button.